# How i can keep the previous content of the DIV?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm receiving  somes data using AJAX response, and then i put them in a list. The code is the follows:

```
$(document).on('change', '#seleccio_test,#seleccio_test2', function(){

    var capaTEST;
    var pagina="show_test_prova.php";
     $.ajax({
                 async:false,    
                 cache:false,   
                 dataType:"json",        
                 type: "POST",   
                 url: pagina,
                 data: "dades_test="+obtenirTest(),
                 success:  function(resultat){ 


    var idtest=0;
    $.each(resultat, function(key, value) {

        if(key !=0){

            for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) { 
                alert("Key:" + key + " /value: " + value+" /index: "+idtest);

                var llistat_test="";
                llistat_test +="<div id='TEST'><ol><li><label for='test' id='etiquetalabel'>"+value[i]+"</label>";
                llistat_test+="<input type='checkbox' id='$capaCONTENT"+idtest+"name='test[]' value='"+value[i]+"'onclick=' onclick='show_content($seleccio_content,$id_capa,$pagina,$idtest,$valor_org,$valor_eval,$valor_test)';>";
                llistat_test+="</div> <ol> <div style='display: none;'> </div></ol></li></ol> ";


                var contenido= $("#"+key);
                contenido.html(llistat_test);
                idtest++;
                    }       
                }

            });

        },
        beforeSend:function(){},
        error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){

        }
    })

})
```

the problem appear when it exist more than one value in a single key, so how i can to fix this problem?

Regards

Comment: Please describe in details whats you problem. Its unclear from this question what is wrong, what you expecting from working code and what you currently get.

Comment: Ok , sorry, i will give you some examples:

As you can see , i'm  expecting a JSON object, this object is generated dynamically and could be:
`
{
"content":["C1","C2",..etc]

}
`
The "content" is the id of a DIV, and the "C1", "C2"..., are the data that i will put inside the DIV throught a list.Acording this example , the result in the first loop is:- C1 and in the second loop, the previous value will be replaced (C1) with the next (C2), the result is:
- C2 , i need something like this: -C1 -C2 (inside list )

Comment: somebody has an idea?¿

Comment: i have done it using append function, but  the values is repeating  , that is :


- C1
-C2
-C2 , how i can to check if the current value exist inside the DIV, in order to avoid the repeating values into the list